# Is there a way to iterate a formula across cells in a multiple selection - Google sheet

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets

In a google sheet, this simple script works to select a single cell, then click a button to decrease the value in the selected cell by 1:

```
function tally() {
 
  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell();
  var value = cell.getValue();
  cell.setValue(value-1);
}
```

Is there a way to do a multiple selection - i.e., select multiple / scattered cells in a table, then iterate the function in each of the selected cells?

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation:

- You can use [getActiveRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactiverange) and assuming that you have a 2D
  array, you can use double [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to deduct one from each cell.
- Then [set](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues) all the values back to the sheet.

### Solution:

```
function tally() {
  const rng = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange();
  const values = rng.getValues().map(r=>r.map(c=>c-1));
  rng.setValues(values);
}
```

Comment: Worked once - then processed only the last of cells selected. (?)

Comment: @JohnDickey unfortunately, I can't reproduce your issue. You need to select the cells with your mouse ( until they have a blue border around them ) and **then** run the script. Can you provide more details on how you execute the function ?

Comment: I select one cell, then run script, then repeat - but I would like to be able to make multiple selections of scattered single cells, then run the script once. Your script works on multiple cells only if I select adjacent cells, which I seldom do.  I guess I don't understand other possibilities (getActiveRangeList?) that might help to operate on multiple scattered selections.